# Convert date from yyyy-mm-dd to utc format

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, utc

I have a date, "2015-06-08". I want convert it to "08 June 2015"

```
String oldDateString = "2015-06-08";
 SimpleDateFormat oldDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd", Locale.getDefault());
 SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());

 Date date = oldDateFormat.parse(oldDateString);
 String result = newDateFormat.format(date);
```

but this does not work correctly. It returns "08 January 2015".  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Why `m` in one format and `M` in the other?

Comment: you should check what is in date after parsing.

Comment: Try using `SimpleDateFormat oldDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());` instead. `mm` format is for minutes in an hour, `MM` for month in year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `yyyy-MM-dd` insted `yyyy-mm-dd` because 'm' in lowercase is minutes. 
Documentation : [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)